# How to Open negative browser url?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, ui-automation, selenium-rc

I need to verify if opening the browser url is not landing to a particular  page. Code snippet is a as below, where open is performed and the page displays 'couldn't open this url' but still exception is thrown from selenium

`Error:`
`"ERROR in invoking Selenium Commands:Timed out after 100000ms".`

Selenium RC command

```
selenium.setTimeout("100000");
selenium.open(url);
```

How to verify negative url's via selenium

Comment: Can you share error-log?

Comment: Edited the post with error log

Comment: What is `selenium.open(url)` ? do you mean `selenium.get(url)` ?

Comment: selenium.open is to open url in browser by selenium RC.

Answer (score 0):

To open url in web browser

```
String browser = "firefox";
//String browser = "chrome";
//String browser = "ie";
@Test
public void googleSearch() {
    WebDriver driver = null;
    if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path-to-chromedriver\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }
    else if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("ie")){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","path-to-IEdriver\IEdriver.exe");
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    }
    else {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
}
```

Comment: i don't have issues in opening url. How to open url which doesn't exist and verify the landing page ???

Answer (score 0):

It could be achieve to get the HTTP status code of requested URL but selenium does not support to get HTTP status code (like 400, 500).

Other approach would be:-

--> Open URL

--> Put assertion for valid text on the page. (It will return fail if URL is invalid else URL is valid)

Comment: open url fails and selenium command failed, How to assert text on page.

Comment: Why open url fails, can you paste the format of URL which you try to open.

Comment: I'm entering url with invalid ip which is expected to fail. I must verify the failure message